# How to charge a battery when the charging socket is broken?

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-charging, speakers

First of all I'll explain my situation: I own a Bluetooth speaker, more precisely this one: http://www.leicke.eu/en/products/EP18108

Due to my clumsy hands it fell while the USB cable was connected to the charging socket, and the USB socket split from the speaker's board. All features of the speakers work great, but I cannot charge it without the socket.

One solution might be to solder the socket back to the mainframe, but it doesn't seem a good idea with my standard soldering iron.

However, I can access to the battery which shows the black and red cable.

I'm not sure if I could charge the battery by connecting directly to a 5V source, or maybe that is not that simple and could damage the rest of the mainboard. Maybe I should take the battery out every time I would need to charge it... maybe you guys knows a better way to connect a charging circuit to this cables and perform a new charging socket in the speakers box.

Could you please give me a hand on this?

Comment: If you can add a picture to show the damage we can help provide solution.

Comment: You cannot charge the battery by directly connecting it to 5 volts, still connected to the device or not. The device circuit includes the battery charger. Directly connecting the battery to a power source could easily damage it or, if a lithium battery, make it explode! Be careful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen to a vaping device. What I did was cut a USB charging cable I had on hand and soldered the wires directly to the board where the charging port was in the vaping device. You'll have to tinker with it to determine where to solder the wires on the board of your speaker, though. Really, you only need the 5v and common wires of the USB cable and it should work fine. Red should be the 5V and black should be your common, but not all cables are the same. If you have a multimeter available, that'll help. You don't want to try to directly charge the battery unless you know what battery is in the device and have a lithium-ion battery charger that is adjustable (charge rate) and has overcharge protection.